# Unable to access token from an external callout through Apex

Tags: callout, accesstoken, credentials

I'm starting developing on Salesforce, and want to retrieve a token from a client webapi to access another api. The client gave some access details to connect to their webapi.

It looks like this :

```
url POST 
https://mywebapi.com/v1/test

Authentification 
grant type : password credential

Access token url 
https://myaccesstoken.com/test/oauth2/token

username
myusername@test.com

Password
xxxyyyzzz

client id
urn:oauth:webapi:test:webapi

client secret
aaabbbccc
```

Not being able to use Named credentials to configure that. I decide to do everything with apex.
So my code looks like this :

```
public with sharing class AuthenticationDetail{
    /*End point Url to web service callout*/
    private final static String ENP_POINT_URL = 'https://myaccesstoken.com/test/oauth2/token';

    private final static String REQUEST_BODY = 'grant_type=password&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&username={2}&password={3}';
    private final static String USERNAME = 'myusername@test.com';
    private final static String PASSWORD = 'xxxyyyzzz';
    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = 'urn:oauth:webapi:test:webapi';
    private final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = 'aaabbbccc';
    
    /*To generate Access token Method*/
    private static OAuth getAccessToken(){
        try{
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(ENP_POINT_URL);
            req.setMethod('POST');          
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);
            String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
            EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
            req.setBody(String.format(REQUEST_BODY ,new string[]{CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                                 USERNAME,PASSWORD}));
            req.setTimeout(60000);
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            OAuth objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth.class);
            return objAuthenticationInfo;
        }catch(CallOutException ce){
            throw ce;
        }
    }
    
    /*To get Access token property*/
    public static OAuth authenticationDetail{
        get{
            if(authenticationDetail == null){
                authenticationDetail = getAccessToken();
            }
            return authenticationDetail;
        }set;
    }
        
    /*To get aouthentication detail Wrapper*/
    public class OAuth{
        public String id{get;set;}
        public String issued_at{get;set;}
        public String instance_url{get;set;}
        public String signature{get;set;}
        public String access_token{get;set;}    
    }   
}
```

But when I do this :

```
system.debug('AuthenticationDetail '+AuthenticationDetail.authenticationDetail);
```

I got this :

```
DEBUG|AuthenticationDetail OAuth:[access_token=null, id=null, instance_url=null, issued_at=null, signature=null]
```

I don't know why whereas a token is generated very well when using Postman with the exact same data.
[image]
[image]

Clicking the "</>" icon on Postman gives me the callout details of `https://mywebapi.com/v1/test` and not of `https://myaccesstoken.com/test/oauth2/token`:
[image]

Please help!

Comment: What kind of help do you expect given that the target endpoint is not Salesforce?

Comment: I want to access an external token with an external endpoint (a non Salesforce endpoint). Isn't that possible with this case?

Comment: please add screen shots of your successful Postman including endpoint, headers and body. Note also that you're not inspecting `res.getStatusCode()` - you won't get a callout exception for 400, 401, 403, etc

Comment: Just updated my post with the postman screenshots on how I get a token

Comment: @Adam Clicking the "</>" icon on Postman gives me the callout details of `https://mywebapi.com/v1/test` and not of `https://myaccesstoken.com/test/oauth2/token`. I updated my post for you to see more

Comment: `Client Authentication` is where you want to look.

Comment: @identigral client authentication on Postman ?

Comment: @kabrice first, let's confirm if the callout gets any data returned, in your apex code, after the line `HttpResponse res = http.send(req);` add `System.debug('Response Status: ' + res.toString() + ', Response Body: ' + res.getBody());`

Comment: I get this : `Response Status: System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400], Response Body: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"MSIS9631 : OAuth request is not valid."}`